# How to pass a list of columns to data.table where some are predetermined

Tags: r, data.table

#### Pass character vectors and column names to `data.table` as a list of columns?

I want to be able to produce a subset of columns in R using data.table in a way that I can determine some of them earlier on and pass the predetermined list on as a character vector, then combine with a static list of columns.

That is, given this:

```
a <- 1:4
b <- 5:8
c <- c('aa','bb','cc','dd')
e <- 1:4

z <- data.table(a,b,c,e)
```

I want to do this:

```
z[, list(a,b)]
```

Which produces this output:

```
   a b
1: 1 5
2: 2 6
3: 3 7
4: 4 8
```

But I want to do it in some way similar to this (which works, almost):

```
cols <- "b"
z[, list(get(cols), a)]
```

Results:
Note that it doesn't return the name of the column stored in `cols`

```
   V1 a
1:  5 1
2:  6 2
3:  7 3
4:  8 4
```

but I need to do it with more than one element of `cols` (which does not work):

```
cols <- c('a', 'b')
z[, list(mget(cols), c)]
```

The above produces the following error:

```
Error: value for ‘a’ not found
```

I think my problem lies with scoping and which environments `mget` is looking in, but I can't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong. Also, how do I preserve the column titles?

Comment: Would `z[,c(cols,'c'),with=FALSE]` be enough? This is probably a duplicate I'm guessing though.

Comment: @thelatemail - This works well in my example and in my own code. 'with=FALSE' is interesting. I don't think I understand the difference between evaluating j within the frame of x (with=TRUE) and having j be a vector of name or positions to select (with=FALSE). Something I need to look into more to understand all of the answers that have been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Combining a variable with column names with hard-coded column names in data.table

Given `z` and `cols` from the example above:

To combine a list of column names in a variable `col` with other hard coded column name `c`, we combine them in a new character vector `c(col, 'c')` in the call to `data.table`. We can refer to `cols` from within `j` (the second argument within `[]`) by using the "up-one-level" notation `..`:

```
z[, c(..cols, 'c')]
```

Thank you to @thelatemail for providing the base to the solution above.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two (pretty much equivalent) options. One using `lapply`:

```
z[, c(lapply(cols, get), list(c))]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  1  5 aa
#2:  2  6 bb
#3:  3  7 cc
#4:  4  8 dd
```

And one using `mget`:

```
z[, c(mget(cols, inherits = TRUE), c = list(c))]
#   a b  c
#1: 1 5 aa
#2: 2 6 bb
#3: 3 7 cc
#4: 4 8 dd
```

Note that `get` returns a vector which loses the information about column name (and there isn't much you can do about it besides manually adding it back in), while `mget` returns a named list.

Comment: This works beautifully with my example. For some reason, however, it doesn't seem to work in the actual code I am using. Probably a flaw in my example. The answer from @mnel works in both cases. Odd - I'll figure out why and make an edit.

Answer (score 4):

Attempting to mix standard and non-standard evaluation within a single call will probably end in tears / frustration / obfusticated code.

There are a number of options in `data.table`

1. Use `..` notation to "look up one level" to find the vector of column names

   ```
   cols <- c('a','b')
   z[, ..cols]
   ```
2. Use `.SDcols`

   ```
   z[, .SD, .SDcols = cols]
   ```

But if you really want to combine the two ways of referencing, then you can use something like (introducing another option, `with=FALSE`, which allows more general expressions for column names than a simple vector)

```
ll <- function(char=NULL,uneval=NULL){ 
        Call <- match.call()
        cols <- lapply(Call$uneval,as.character)
         unlist(c(char,cols))}
z[, ll(cols,c), with=FALSE]
#    a b  c
# 1: 1 5 aa
# 2: 2 6 bb
# 3: 3 7 cc
# 4: 4 8 dd

z[, ll(char=cols), with=FALSE]
#    a b
# 1: 1 5
# 2: 2 6
# 3: 3 7
# 4: 4 8

z[, ll(uneval=c), with=FALSE]
#     c
# 1: aa
# 2: bb
# 3: cc
# 4: dd
```

Comment: This works great. I don't know why it works with both the example and the actual code I'm working with while the answer from @eddi does not. I'll try to figure that out.