# data.table avoid column name changing

Tags: r, data.table

once again I realize that there is still so much to learn ...

```
dt <- data.table(   A = c("r1"  ,"r1"   ,"r1"   ,"r2"   ,"r2"), B = c("p1"  ,"p2","p3","p2" ,"p3"), M =  c(5    ,50 ,30 ,40 ,50))

### the groups - this can not be changed
theGroups <- c("A", "B")
### loop through groups - the looping can not be changed
for(i in theVertices){
dt.Group <- dt[,list(get(i),M)] #<- this can be changed
###... other things will happen here
print(dt.Group)}
```

My question is why the columname changes from A to V1 and from B to V1, obviously the proper columns are used that's why there is the print (just for demonstration) and if there is some way to avoid this?
I know that I can rename the V1-column name, but I want to know why this happens.

Thanks

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24274815/559784) is very much related (or even answers exactly)? If so, please write back and I'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: It absolutely answers my question, I guess I was somewhat biased by the column name change searching for an answer. Your hint definitely saves my weekend. Thanks Tom