# Using both vectors of column names and hard-coded columns in j

Tags: r, data.table

(I can never fully remember how `j` is evaluated in `data.table`,
every time when I need to call variable-defined columns in `j`, I have to go through some trial-and-error with `.()`, `c()`, `get()`, `with=FALSE`, and `..`)
For the following example I just failed to find a right combination...

I need to select some columns and also add one column computed from others, something like this:

```
require(data.table)
data("mtcars")
setDT(mtcars)

mtcars[,.(mpg,   cyl,disp,  newcol=carb*3)]
#     mpg cyl  disp newcol
# 1: 21.0   6 160.0     12
# 2: 21.0   6 160.0     12
# 3: 22.8   4 108.0      3
# 4: 21.4   6 258.0      3
# 5: 18.7   8 360.0      6
```

However, my issue is that some column names are stored in character vectors:

```
mycols <- c('cyl', 'disp')
mycol3 <- 'carb'
```

...whereas another variable, `mpg`, is provided interactively ("hard-coded"). I was trying something like

```
mtcars[,c('mpg',   mycols,  'newcol' = 'mycol3'*3)]
# Error in "mycol3" * 3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

mtcars[,c('mpg',   mycols,  'newcol' = mycol3*3), with=FALSE]
# Error in mycol3 * 3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

mtcars[,.(mpg,   get(mycols), newcol = get(mycol3)*3)]
# not an error but not the desired output:
#     mpg V2 newcol
# 1: 21.0  6     12
# 2: 21.0  6     12
# 3: 22.8  4      3
# 4: 21.4  6      3
# 5: 18.7  8      6
```

So far I found a workaround but it's really ugly:

```
mtcars[ , c('mpg',   mycols,  mycol3), with=F
        ][ , ('newcol') := get(mycol3)*3
           ][ , c('mpg',mycols,'newcol'), with=F]
```

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `list`. This does not modify the object

```
 mtcars[,c(mget(mycols), .(newcol = get(mycol3)*3))]
    cyl  disp newcol
 1:   6 160.0     12
 2:   6 160.0     12
 3:   4 108.0      3
 4:   6 258.0      3
 5:   8 360.0      6
 6:   6 225.0      3
 7:   8 360.0     12
 8:   4 146.7      6
 9:   4 140.8      6
```

edit:
as [@Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752474/using-both-vectors-of-column-names-and-hard-coded-columns-in-j/63785057#comment112808132_63785057) pointed out, we need the `mpg` variable too:

```
mtcars[,c(mget(mycols), .(newcol = get(mycol3)*3, mpg = mpg))]
    cyl  disp newcol  mpg
 1:   6 160.0     12 21.0
 2:   6 160.0     12 21.0
 3:   4 108.0      3 22.8
 4:   6 258.0      3 21.4
 5:   8 360.0      6 18.7
```

or even

```
mtcars[,c(mget(mycols), .(newcol = get(mycol3)*3), .(mpg = mpg))]
    cyl  disp newcol  mpg
 1:   6 160.0     12 21.0
 2:   6 160.0     12 21.0
 3:   4 108.0      3 22.8
 4:   6 258.0      3 21.4
 5:   8 360.0      6 18.7
 6:   6 225.0      3 18.1
```

That is, just add the the named variable `mpg` or any other into the list.

Comment: cool! I didn't know `j` can have `list()` inside `c()` - not sure if this type of constructs are included in `data.table` vignettes or reference...

Comment: @VasilyA `c(..list(..))`  is a base R construction. `j` needs to be a list, and you could `c`oncatenate two lists together, still to obtain another list. Recall this is not a list of lists but rather just one list with more elements. eg try `c(list(1,2), 3)` or `c(1,2,list(3))`, or `c(list(1,2), list(3))` and see what happens. All of them should be the same. So what did I do? I used the second fact to produce what I want.. if this answers the question, please accept the answer to close the question

Comment: @VasilyA See the Examples in `?data.table`, where you find the `c(list(something), <a list>)` construct: `DT[, c(.(y=max(y)), lapply(.SD, min))`. This is a rather common use case, where the result of `lapply(.SD` is a list, to which you the `c`oncatenate another list element, `.(y=max(y))`. Then the fundamental property of `j` kicks in: "As long as `j` returns a list, each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting `data.table`". Cheers

Comment: Somewhat related reading: [How to pass a list of columns to data.table where some are predetermined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274815/how-to-pass-a-list-of-columns-to-data-table-where-some-are-predetermined); [Combining .SD with renamed variable messes with names of .SD columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281389/combining-sd-with-renamed-variable-messes-with-names-of-sd-columns) ("_programmatically select some variables and select and rename some others in a hard coded way_")

Comment: @Onyambu and Vasily: For the sake of completeness and for future visitors, perhaps also include `mpg` in `j`, which was a part of the original issue: combining both programmatically selected variables and a hard-coded one (mpg). Cheers

Comment: @Henrik did that. Thanks for pointing that out. Forgot about it

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for taking your time!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this in `data.table` :

1. Add new columns.
2. Select all the columns needed.

```
library(data.table)

df <- mtcars
setDT(df)
cols <- c('mpg', mycols, 'newcol')
df[, newcol := get(mycol3)*3]
df[ , ..cols]

#    mpg cyl  disp newcol
#1: 21.0   6 160.0     12
#2: 21.0   6 160.0     12
#3: 22.8   4 108.0      3
#4: 21.4   6 258.0      3
#5: 18.7   8 360.0      6
#6: 18.1   6 225.0      3
#...
#...
```

---

If you want to do this in one-liner :

```
df[, newcol := get(mycol3)*3][, ..cols]
```

Comment: hmmm so there's really no way to have it in one `[ ]` call? (not critical of course, was just curious if it's possible at all)

Comment: also, with this solution there's unwanted `carb` column that I'll have to remove somehow...

Comment: @VasilyA Check updated answer to get the same exact output. I also added an alternate one-liner.

Comment: thanks! the only small thing I don't like is that the original table becomes modified. So far I've resorted to explicitly copying an object: `copy(df)[, newcol := get(mycol3)*3][, ..cols]`. Do you know is there any other way to prevent modifying original table?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `.SDcols`

```
library(data.table)
mtcars[,  newcol := .SD[[1]] *3,.SDcols = mycol3]
```

Comment: thank you akrun, I didn't think about this direction! Ideally I would prefer to not modify the original table though.